# password authentication failed for user error in django project

Tags: python, django

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user 'admin'`

please help I am new to django, this is my first project, I'm getting this error when i try to run migration and runserver.

Comment: your database either does not have an admin user or you have not set the proper password ... you could just use sqlite and that would probably solve it for now ...

Comment: @Egwuemi JerryJude - I think Joran is right. You need to use your Database User and Password while connecting to the Database in settings.py.

Comment: @ Egwuemi JerryJude - Sqlite will be a quick fix but for the most part, if you choose to use Postgres or Mysql, you will need to resolve it  by specifying the right credentials

Comment: absolutely ... you will need to solve this long term ... but using sqlite is a quick fix that can get you going fast (assuming this is a new project you are working on as opposed to an existing project you are trying to work on as part of a team)

Answer (score -2):

Did you set the `admin` password?

```
$ python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/